# HTML - In browser viewing and forced downloads

Tags: php, html

On the website I am working on I like to offer users two links for every download, "View" and "Download".  Most if not all of these downloads will be PDF format.  The goal of View is to cause the document to be displayed in the browser with the PDF plugin/extension, whereas the Download link forces a download to local storage.

I have it working this way:

```
<div class="DownloadLinks">
    <a href="./images/services/example.pdf">View</a> 
    <a href="./images/services/example.pdf" download="">Download</a></div>
</div>
```

But now I want to do it this way (using PHP to store and retrieve documents) and it doesn't work any more:

```
<div class="DownloadLinks">
    <div class="DownloadLinks"><a href="./get_document.php?doc_id=3">View</a> 
    <a href="./get_document.php?doc_id=3" download="">Download</a></div>
</div>
```

I think the problem might be that the browser doesn't see a file extension in the link therefore performs a download instead of firing up the PDF plugin.  Unfortunately I am just using a Content Management System and I don't have access to the PHP script and I can't change any of that.  How can I get this to work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just using javascript because of your CMS. Here's a good function for that.

```
var downloadURL = function downloadURL(url) {
    var hiddenIFrameID = 'hiddenDownloader', iframe = document.getElementById(hiddenIFrameID);
    if (iframe === null) {
        iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.id = hiddenIFrameID;
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
    }
    iframe.src = url;
};
```

This would be for the download script. If you wanted to uses php so that you could also track the number of downloads (or something along thos lines), your could just use AJAX for that.

Comment: So I would call this function from an onclick attribute I put in the link?  ie onclick="downloadURL('./get_document.php?doc_id=3')"???  I tried this but didn't do anything...

Comment: Actually, it's meant so that you can download the file with just javascript. So `onclick="downloadURL('files/doc1.pdf')"`

Comment: ok but PHP is fetching the file for us (hence calling get_document.php).  I don't have the actual filename to work with.  It's how were supposed to store documents on the CMS.

Comment: Yes but you can also use an absolute link: `onclick="downloadURL('http://courses.be.washington.edu/LARCH/440/FileType.pdf')"`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know where the files are stored on the server.  They are uploaded using the CMS and then it gives me a link ie. "get_document.php?doc_id=3".

Comment: Oh, sorry I couldn't help. But if you do find a way to get the link to a file or you decide on a different way to host files, for example Dropbox, javascript would be able to solve your problem. Good luck with your problem though!

Comment: Just to clarify: This function works by creating an iframe (which is hidden??) and setting url to the one given.  What exactly does that do for us?

Comment: The iframe with the `src` to the non text file forces the browser to download the file instead of allowing it to be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following headers to get_document.php when you click the download link (you may need an extra GET parameter to indicate this):

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

Where $file is a path to your file, alternatively you can manually substitute the name and file size, but make sure the name includes the correct extension.

Edit, you say you don't have access to the CMS - how about the HTTP server? Or is it a hosted service?